# Querying Firestore multi level depth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my firestore architecture looks like this:

**/customers/{customerid}/users/{randomuserid}**

where the {customerid} and {randomuserid} is a random id generate by firestore.

the user document:

- username = string
- password = string

*pseudo code:*
`collection("customers")......where("username", "==", "user1234")`

how can i now query all users?

thanks,
Stefan

Comment: You are looking for [`collectionGroup()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries. `db.collectionGroup("users").where(...)`

Comment: I think your comment would be better suited as an answer.

Comment: Yes Peter, but there were multiple duplicates of this so I didn't :D